# Why can't I fetch www.google.com with Perl's LWP::Simple?

Tags: perl, web-crawler

I cant seem to get this peice of code to work:

```
    $self->{_current_page} = $href;
    my $response = $ua->get($href);
    my $responseCode = $response->code;
    if( $responseCode ne "404" ) {
       my $content = LWP::Simple->get($href);
       die "get failed: " . $href if (!defined $content);
    }
```

Will return error: `get failed: http://www.google.com`

The full code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use URI;
use URI::http;
use File::Basename;
use DBI;
use LWP::Simple;
require LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;
$ua->max_redirect(0);


package Crawler;
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {
        _url => shift,
        _max_link => 0,
        _local => 1
    };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;

}
sub trim{
    my( $self, $string ) = @_;
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $string;
}
sub process_image {
    my ($self, $process_image) = @_;
    $self->{_process_image} = $process_image;
}
sub local {
    my ($self, $local) = @_;
    $self->{_local} = $local;
}
sub max_link {
    my ($self, $max_link) = @_;
    $self->{_max_link} = $max_link;
}
sub x_more {
    my ($self, $x_more) = @_;
    $self->{_x_more} = $x_more;
}
sub resolve_href {
    my ($base, $href) = @_;
    my $uri = URI->new($href);
    return $uri->rel($base);    
}
sub write {
    my ( $self, $ref, $data ) = @_;
    open FILE, '>c:/perlscripts/' . $ref . '_' . $self->{_process_image} . '.txt';
    foreach( $data ) {
        print FILE $self->trim($_) . "\n";
    }
    close( FILE );
}
sub scrape {
    my @m_error_array;
    my @m_href_array;
    my @href_array;
    my ( $self, $DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpass, $DBname ) = @_;
    my ($dbh, $query, $result, $array);
    my $DNS = "dbi:mysql:$DBname:$DBhost:3306";
    $dbh = DBI->connect($DNS, $DBuser, $DBpass ) or die $DBI::errstr;
    if( defined( $self->{_process_image} ) && ( -e 'c:/perlscripts/href_w_' . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt" ) ) {
        open  ERROR_W, "<c:/perlscripts/error_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
        open  M_HREF_W, "<c:/perlscripts/m_href_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
        open  HREF_W, "<c:/perlscripts/href_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
        @m_error_array = <ERROR_W>;
        @m_href_array = <M_HREF_W>;
        @href_array = <HREF_W>;
        close ( ERROR_W );
        close ( M_HREF_W );
        close ( HREF_W );
    }else{
        @href_array = ( $self->{_url} );
    }
    my $z = 0;
    while( @href_array ){
        if( defined( $self->{_x_more} ) && $z == $self->{_x_more} ) {
            last;
        }
        if( defined( $self->{_process_image} ) ) {
            $self->write( 'm_href_w', @m_href_array );
            $self->write( 'href_w', @href_array );
            $self->write( 'error_w', @m_error_array );
        }
        $self->{_link_count} = scalar @m_href_array;
        my $href = shift( @href_array );
        my $info = URI::http->new($href);
        my $host = $info->host;
        $host =~ s/^www\.//;
        $result = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `". $host ."` (URL) VALUES ('$href')");
        if( ! $result->execute() ){
            $result = $dbh->prepare("CREATE TABLE `" . $host . "` ( `ID` INT( 255 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `URL` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )) ENGINE = MYISAM ;");
            $result->execute();
        }
        $self->{_current_page} = $href;
        my $response = $ua->get($href);
        my $responseCode = $response->code;
        if( $responseCode ne "404" ) {
           my $content = LWP::Simple->get($href);
           die "get failed: " . $href if (!defined $content);
        }
        #print $responseCode;
    }
}
1;

#$query = "SELECT * FROM `actwebdesigns.co.uk` ORDER BY ID DESC";
#$result = $dbh->prepare($query);
#$result->execute();
#while( $array = $result->fetchrow_hashref() ) {
#    print $array->{'URL'} . "\n";
#}
```

EDIT:

Still not working with redirect fixed.

```
my $redirect_limit = 10;
    my $y = 0;
    while( 1 && $y le $redirect_limit ) {
        my $response = $ua->get($href);
        my $responseCode = $response->code;
        if( $responseCode == 200 || $responseCode == 301 || $responseCode == 302 ) {
            if( $responseCode == 301 || $responseCode == 302 ) {
                $href = $response->header('Location');
            }else{
                last;
            }
        }else{
            push( @m_error_array, $href );
            last;
        }
        $y++;
    }
    if( $y ne $redirect_limit ) {
        if( ! defined( $self->{_url_list} ) ) {
            my @url_list = ( $href );
        }else{
            my @url_list = $self->{_url_list};
            push( @url_list, $href );
            $self->{_url_list} = @url_list;
        }
        my $content = LWP::Simple->get($href);
        die "get failed: " . $href if (!defined $content);

        #$result = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `". $host ."` (URL) VALUES ('$href')");
        #if( ! $result->execute() ){
        #    $result = $dbh->prepare("CREATE TABLE `" . $host . "` ( `ID` INT( 255 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `URL` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )) ENGINE = MYISAM ;");
        #    $result->execute();
        #}
        print "good";
    }else{
        push( @m_error_array, $href );
    }
```

Comment: Why are you fetching the page twice?  Use `$response->content` instead of `LWP::Simple->get($href)`.

Comment: thank you, right on the money!

Comment: When you have a problem, reduce it to the shortest example script that demonstrates the problem. Strip away everything else in your program. Find out which data trigger the problem. Often, by going through that process, you find your answe

Answer (score 2):

You should examine the response code to see what's happening (you're already checking for 404s).  I get a [302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) - a redirect.

For example:

```
die "get failed ($responseCode): " . $href if (!defined $content);
```

Resulting message:

```
get failed (302): http://www.google.com at goog.pl line 20.
```

Comment: Ha, what a mupet! trusted google.com localises to .co.uk... should have known this. Regards!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of thoughts.

1/ You seems to be using the string comparison operators (le, ne) to compare numbers. You should use the numeric comparison operators (<=, !=) instead.

2/ The value you get back from the [LWP::UserAgent::get](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::UserAgent#REQUEST_METHODS) call is an [HTTP::Response](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Response) object. Judicious use of that class's "is_foo" method might make your code a bit cleaner.

I don't know if either of these will solve your problem. But they'll improve the quality of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
my $content = LWP::Simple->get($href);
```

That passes the string "LWP::Simple" as the first argument to 'get'. You want:

```
my $content = LWP::Simple::get($href);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your SELinux settings.

SELINUX enabled systems will not allow an outgoing connection from a web agent (httpd).

This page can tell you more about SELinux and HTTPD settings:
http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans

Enable outbound web connections from Apache in a Perl script:

```
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

Comment: If you are downvoting an answer please comment as to why.