# Perl Can not open the source page on slackware

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I fetch www.google.com with Perl's LWP::Simple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757693/why-cant-i-fetch-www-google-com-with-perls-lwpsimple)

code below can be used to open the source page in windows,

but why in linux (slackware) I could not??

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
use LWP::Simple;
$URL = get("http://google.com");
print $URL;
```

Comment: It works fine on my Linux system.  What sort of errors are you getting?

Comment: no error message, that's what makes me wonder..

Comment: i dont understand. can you fix the above code to work?

Comment: You need to add warnings and strict. $URL may be undef because the get() call fails - without warnings, you won't be told about it.

Comment: You haven't said if you're running this as a CGI script or at the command line.  If it's a CGI, try running it from the command line first.

Comment: If you use LWP::UserAgent's `get` instead, you'll get an error message in the `->status_line` of the returned response instead of just getting `undef`. It could be that the your system doesn't allow outgoing connections from CGI scripts, which begs the question: Did you try running this from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print get('http://google.com');
```

Changes:

- Always(!) use strict and warnings.
- Move use statements to start of script.
- Eliminate use of $URL - you'll get a warning if the get() call fails even without it.

Comment: "Move use statements to start of script" because it's not like the `print` was happening before the module was loaded.